# Compute Engine being underutilized

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

I got a notification saying that my VM instance was being underutilized and that I should change to a lower specification. If I do that, would I lose all the data on the VM.

Comment: Usually no.  However, I always shutdown the VM and create an image of the boot/data disks before changing anything.